# Can't install updates or any new mac OS installations on macbook pro (2012)

Tags: mac, macbook, osx-lion

I had Catalina installed on my 2012 Macbook Pro.

I had an installation of windows bootcamp and ubuntu.

I had a error occur with my boot loader and I had to resort to the macbook internet recovery mode in order to revive my macbook. I had done a fresh instal of OS X (Mountain Lion).

Now I cannot update OS X from within system preference,

- Downloading Catalina from the app store says I require macOS version 10.9 or later.
- Downloading Sierra works but then I try to run the installer (got it from the app store) and it says "this version of Sierra application is damaged."
- Downloaded Catalina from apples website and it says the "The following disk image is corrupt"

I've reinstalled the mountain lion OS again through recovery mode (after erasing my disc). Tried all the same steps as above and similar errors.

I'm out of options, I also do not have a secondary macbook in order to create a bootable Catalina usb (I only have a windows desktop and this).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello. Did you check your hard disk for errors?  Disk Utility is found in the /Applications/Utilities/ folder. Select the disk from the list at the left of the Disk Utility screen. Look for the “S.M.A.R.T. Status” of the disk information overview in Disk Utility:  If the SMART Status says “Verified” the drive is in good health.  If S.M.A.R.T. Status says “Failing” the drive needs to be replaced. source: http://osxdaily.com/2018/05/31/how-check-smart-status-mac-hard-disk/

Comment: See Nohillside's answer below & its links, but note you **must** install El Capitan first, before you can install anything newer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the second screenshot it seems that you've downloaded the update from 10.15.0 to 10.15.1, not the 10.15 installer as such. You can get proper installers for various versions of OSX and macOS directly from Apple, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208052 for a list (and links to downloadable versions).

There are more details beneath [this question on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos) but the Apple link above should be all you need to get started.